# Zope/Plone code reload after deployment on production

Tags: deployment, plone, continuous-deployment, zope, zodb

Is there a way to reload the code without restarting Zope when in Production ?
New features are implemented almost once in 2 days and have to be uploaded to the server. The only way it works currently is by restarting the zeo server and all instances. Can't use "plone.reload" as it only works in the development environment when the debug mode is on. Below is the buildout.cfg content

```
[buildout]


  parts =
#    instance
        zeo
        client1
        client2
        client3
        zopepy
        zopeskel
        test
#    mysql
#    varnish-build
#    varnish
    supervisor
    pidproxy

extends =
    https://dist.plone.org/versions/zope-2-13-19-versions.cfg
find-links =
    https://dist.plone.org/release/4.2.4
    https://dist.plone.org/thirdparty
extensions =
    mr.developer
#    buildout.dumppickedversions
sources = sources
versions = versions
develop =

[versions]
plone.recipe.zeoserver = 1.3.1
plone.recipe.zope2instance = 4.2.8
five.localsitemanager = 2.0.5
Products.PluginRegistry = 1.3
Products.CMFCore = 2.2.7
Products.GenericSetup = 1.7.3
Products.ZSQLMethods = 2.13.4
zope.interface = 3.6.7
zope.app.publication = 3.12.0
#setuptools = 17.1.1
funcsigs = 0.4
openpyxl = 2.4.0
plone.reload = 2.0.2

[zeo]
recipe = plone.recipe.zeoserver
zeo-address = 127.0.0.1:9100
zeo-var = ${buildout:directory}/var
blob-storage = ${zeo:zeo-var}/blobstorage
#ggs = plone.app.blob

[client1]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
http-address = 9081
zeo-client = on
zeo-address =  ${zeo:zeo-address}
shared-blob = on
blob-storage =  ${zeo:zeo-var}/blobstorage
user = admin:Slick_RP@21!
products = ${buildout:directory}/matrix_git/prod/
debug-mode = off
verbose-security = off
eggs =
#    pillow
    mysql-python
    simplejson
    haversine
    openpyxl
    requests
    httpagentparser
    ordereddict
    python-memcached
#    python-crontab
#   setuptools
    Products.CMFCore
    Products.ZMySQLDA
#    Products.SQLAlchemyDA
    Products.PluggableAuthService
#    Products.ZopeProfiler
#    Products.MemoryProfiler
#    reportlab
    Products.BeakerSessionDataManager
    collective.fsexternalmethod
    plone.reload
zope-conf-additional =
    extensions ${buildout:directory}/matrix_git/Extensions
    <product-config beaker>
        session.type            file
        session.data_dir        ${buildout:directory}/var/sessions/data
        session.lock_dir        ${buildout:directory}/var/sessions/lock
        session.key             beaker.session
        session.secret          secret
    </product-config>
zcml =
    collective.fsexternalmethod
    plone.reload
event-log-max-size = 5 MB
event-log-old-files = 5
access-log-max-size = 20 MB
access-log-old-files = 10

[client2]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
http-address = 9082
zeo-client = ${client1:zeo-client}
zeo-address = ${client1:zeo-address}
blob-storage = ${client1:blob-storage}
shared-blob = ${client1:shared-blob}
user = ${client1:user}
products = ${client1:products}
debug-mode = off
verbose-security = off
eggs = ${client1:eggs}
zcml = ${client1:zcml}
zope-conf-additional = ${client1:zope-conf-additional}
event-log-max-size = ${client1:event-log-max-size}
event-log-old-files = ${client1:event-log-old-files}
access-log-max-size = ${client1:access-log-max-size}
access-log-old-files = ${client1:access-log-old-files}

[client3]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
http-address = 9083
zeo-client = ${client1:zeo-client}
zeo-address = ${client1:zeo-address}
blob-storage = ${client1:blob-storage}
shared-blob = ${client1:shared-blob}
user = ${client1:user}
products = ${client1:products}
debug-mode = off
verbose-security = off
eggs = ${client1:eggs}
zcml = ${client1:zcml}
zope-conf-additional = ${client1:zope-conf-additional}
event-log-max-size = ${client1:event-log-max-size}
event-log-old-files = ${client1:event-log-old-files}
access-log-max-size = ${client1:access-log-max-size}
access-log-old-files = ${client1:access-log-old-files}
[zopepy]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ${client1:eggs}
interpreter = zopepy
scripts = zopepy

[test]
recipe = zc.recipe.testrunner
defaults = ['--auto-color', '--auto-progress']
eggs =
    ${client1:eggs}

[zopeskel]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =
    ZopeSkel
    PasteScript

[mysql]
recipe = zest.recipe.mysql
# Note that these urls usually stop working after a while... thanks...
mysql-url = http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/mysql-5.0/mysql-5.0.86.tar.gz
mysql-python-url = http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz

[varnish-build]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = ${varnish:download-url}

[varnish]
recipe = plone.recipe.varnish
daemon = ${buildout:parts-directory}/varnish-build/sbin/varnishd
bind = 127.0.0.1:8000
backends = 127.0.0.1:8080
cache-size = 50M

[pidproxy]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = supervisor
scripts = pidproxy

[supervisor]
recipe = collective.recipe.supervisor
port = 127.0.0.1:24007
serverurl = http://127.0.0.1:24007
programs =
#    10 mysql      ${buildout:directory}/bin/pidproxy [${buildout:directory}/var/mysql/mysql.pid ${buildout:directory}/parts/mysql/install/bin/mysqld_safe --pid-file=${buildout:directory}/var/mysql/mysql.pid --socket=${buildout:directory}/var/mysql.socket] ${buildout:directory} true
    20 zeo       ${buildout:directory}/bin/zeo [console] ${buildout:directory} true
    30 client1   ${buildout:directory}/bin/client1 [console] ${buildout:directory} true
    40 client2   ${buildout:directory}/bin/client2 [console] ${buildout:directory} true
    50 client3   ${buildout:directory}/bin/client3 [console] ${buildout:directory} true
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to restart the ZODB server? Short of replication settings or adding new database mounts, that's hardly ever needed for code changes.

Comment: Yes.. otherwise it does not seem to take effect. I've updated the question with my buildout.cfg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are deploying so frequently, you can either deploy at low traffic times (i.e. at night).

If the website should be always up, you could have two sets of Plone instances: one set is active and serving requests, the second one is not active.

When updating, the offline servers are updated and when they are done, a switch is turned (HAProxy for example) to replace the active servers.

You could even have all servers available always, but for updating, put some offline while they are updated.

As others, and you as well are pointing, I would never use plone.reload or similar development tools in production.

Comment: seems like a good idea.. i guess this is what all the big organisations do.. have multiple nodes and switch between them either in the case of a failure of some of the nodes or deployment. Thanks

Comment: The question was not if it's a good or bad idea, but if it's possible ;-)

Comment: Yes.. it is possible to implement the above idea

Comment: @Ravi Not sure if you were addressing me, but there's a difference between a reload and restarts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way, allthough I'd ***never do that in production*** it's a great time-saver when developing, to do a reload within a browser-view:

```
from plone.reload.code import reload_code
from Products.Five.browser import BrowserView


class View(BrowserView):

    def __call__(self):
        reload_code()
        return 'Code loaded.'
```

Then call the view with the name you registered it with upon the site. This even works in non-debug-mode while the instance is running in background. Tested with a standalone instance (non-ZEO).

Comment: There are few browser views in the system. The code has been recently moved from ZMI based to disk based i.e,. used as a Product now.

Comment: The question is more about how to reload JS, CSS, page template files, zsql files.

Comment: Well then you might want to rephrase the quest "reload the code without restarting Zope" to something more fitting :) With "zsql" you mean "zcml"? I haven't found a reliable way to update them without a restart. For CSS+JS it depends if they are skin-based (no restart necessary) or browser-based (my add-on "adi.ttw_styles" allows styling without a restart) or bundle-based (no idea, if, or not possible without restart, though I doubt there's a way).